# How can I transform w3c.dom.Document to File without save to file

Tags: java, file, document

I have array of `Document` (w3c.dom.Document) - `Document[] arrayOfDocuments;` and I need transform this array to array of `File` - `File[] arrayOfFiles;`, then I will make `zip` file from this `arrayOfFiles`.

I don't know hot to transform `Document` to `File`, it is possible without save to hard disc? And how?

Thank you for your help.

Edit: I want make `zip` file of xml documents.

Comment: A `File` object represents an entry in the file system, which can exist or not at the moment, and which can also be a directory. A `Document` represents markup text structure, which may or may not originate in a file, and may or may not be saved later in a file. How do you suggest relating the one to the other?

Comment: Is there any way, how to make `zip` file from `Document` (**without save some tmp files to disc**) and save this `zip` to file disc?

Comment: Research `ZipOutputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the class called `ZipOutputStream` to zip the files into an output stream. Here is an example:

```
public static void write(OutputStream zipout, Document... docs) 
        throws IOException {

    try (final ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(zipout)) {

        for (final Document doc : docs) {
            final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(doc.getDocumentURI()); // The name
            zip.putNextEntry(entry);
            write(doc, zip);
            zip.closeEntry();
        }
    }
}

public static void write(Document doc, OutputStream out) {
    try {
        final TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        final Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");

        transformer.transform(
            new DOMSource(doc), 
            new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8"))
        );

    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException 
                 | TransformerException 
                 | TransformerFactoryConfigurationError 
                 | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {

        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

The `zipout` can be any output stream, for an example a stream to a file created using `Files.newOutputStream(path)` or to a socket. You don't need to save anything to disk if you don't want to.

Note that every zip entry need a name. In this case, I named the entries using `doc.getDocumentURI()`. You probably want to change that into something else depending on what types of documents you are archiving.